# How do i access a static member from my own custom class loader?

Tags: java, dynamic, static, classloader

I have created my own custom class loader for loading a class to JVM. i can access the non static members using following code

```
MyLoader c=new MyLoader();
Class cls=c.loadClass("Hello");
Object obj=cls.newInstance()
cls.getMethod("show").invoke(obj);
```

But i don't know the procedure for accessing a static memebrs of a loaded class. Kindly provide a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// String.class here is the parameter type, that might not be the case with you
Method method = clazz.getMethod("methodName", String.class);
Object o = method.invoke(null, "whatever");
```

In case the method is private use `getDeclaredMethod()` instead of `getMethod()`. And call `setAccessible(true)` on the method object.

[for static methods we can use null as instance of class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Answer (score 1):

If you have static class members, you can access them just exactly calling from Class `Class.myStaticMemeber`. Static members also are called Class member, as you can call them directly from the class. Of course you can call them using the instance too, such as `cls.myStaticMember`, but you should remember that changing value of static member in one place will make this change to all places where you have called that static member.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. in a normal situation i can access the static members as you specified. But here i am loading a class using my own class loader instead of system class loader. Here 'MyLoader' is my own class loader it load the class 'Hello' into a memory and return the class reference to 'cls'. In this way how do i access a static member?